# Is possible to set dynamic source of bitmap to android XML drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, dynamicresource

XML code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- another items -->
    <item>
       <Bitmap android:src="@drawable/drawable_by_argument"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In code above i want to set Bitmap android:src attribute dynamicaly by some argument.
Something like:

Java code

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back, R.drawable.some_img);
```

Is it possible. If yes how can i do it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

no.
it's not possible.

XML is not dynamic, it's static and heavy parsed during compiling time.